# How to open Github for Windows 11 Git Shell on right click?

Tags: windows-11

[enter image description here][1]I have upgrade windows 10 to windows 11. Then I have lost my git bash on right click menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX0Y3.png)

Comment: https://thegeekpage.com/add-any-program-to-right-click-context-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not gone, it's just hidden (by Windows 11 of course). Click on "Show More Option" then you will see that thing

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2M61.png)